# Sql INSERT into Statement error

Tags: java, sql, database

Please help me in finding the syntax error, i have tried my best to point out but can't.

```
 String sql= "insert into ctable ("

        +"id,"
        +"name,"
        +"address,"
        +"phone,"
        +"email,"
        +"sale_Limit )"

        + "values (" +txtid.getText()+ ",'" +txtname.getText()+ "','" +txtaddress.getText()

        +"','" + txtphone.getText()+ "','"+ txtemail.getText()+ "','"+txtsaleLimit.getText()

        + "')";
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The Error message is : Syntax Error in insert into Statement.

Comment: can you check what the sql string becomes? there may be some values missing in your sql and that makes the query incomplete

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Just print out the sql string on your screen and you can then check how it looks like.

Comment: @codo did you check that Access is not case sensitive?

Comment: Have you checked for a field with a single quote in e.g. a name like "Tim O'Shea"? This will cause your SQL to fail because you are not using parameterised queries (Refer to Jon Skeet's answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *immediate* problem may well be missing quotes.

The *bigger* problem is that you're including data directly in your SQL. You should be using parameterized SQL instead (via a `PreparedStatement`), to [avoid SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), separate code (SQL) from data (values), and to avoid data loss due to string conversions.

Comment: thanks Jon for sharing the link too i have found too much than i have expected.

Answer (score 4):

`name` is reserved word in Access, so you should change column name to others.

As other answer point out, I would recommend you look into [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid possible [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) will help you escape special character as well, for example `'` char in which to avoid SQL syntax error.

[Access reserved words.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335)

Answer (score 1):

Forgot the single quotes?

```
" +txtid.getText()+ "
```

Comment: id is always an integer, that should not have a single quotes

Comment: It is expected to be an integer identifier, so that would not be an issue.

Comment: I doubt it, I bet the id field is a number which doesn't require qoutes.

Comment: @Nick, id fields don't have to be number types.

Comment: No the error is not of id single quotes, i have changed it to single too but doesn't work.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, ok I would say **if id is an integer, then it doesn't require a single quote**

Comment: The same string i have used in another project and that one works well.

Comment: @codo - I would have suggested you to use `PreparedStatement` to not face such assumptions and arguments.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need a space between `"sale_Limit )"` and `"values"`

Comment: At the very least, that's not true in SQL server and oracle, but I haven't tried with other databases.

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN )
                       VALUES
                       ( value1, value2,...valueN );

Remove the inverted commas and addition sign from the field name portion.

Comment: Have you noticed that he is building a string in java?

Answer (score -1):

+"sale_Limit )" - should be space, change to:

```
+"sale_Limit ) "
```

"values (" +txtid.getText()+ ",'" - missing quotes, change to:

```
"values ('" +txtid.getText()+ ",'"
```

Comment: -1 duplicate of other answers and missing closing quote (if quotes were a problem)